# How to minimize or maximize part of window in android studio (shortcut)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Well, as you know, Google has shown Android Studio! And I would like to know how to minimize or maximize part of window in Android Studio using shortcut. I can minimize or maximize part of window using double click to tab. For example, in Eclipse it's CTRL + M to minimize or maximize part of window .

P. S. Sorry for my English. It isn't my natural language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest shortcut to your expected outcome that I know of is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>. This will toggle between minimising and restoring the tool windows.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to hide bottom and side panels like android monitor (logcat and other debug stuff), terminal, etc.

Comment: how to bring them back? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same keyboard shortcut as of Eclipse in Android Studio as well.

To do that go to **Preferences**/Settings of Android Studio. In the left pane navigate to **Keymap**.
In the search bar on the right pane type **Hide All Tool Windows**. Double click on the result -> Add Keyboard Shortcut -> Enter the keyboard shortcut you want. In your case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and save.

This will assign the same shortcut as of Eclipse to Android Studio.